# How to use .net Framework 3.5 on SSIS 2012

Tags: c#, ssis

I am running SQL Server 2012 on a Windows 2012R2 machine, and I am finding it very problematic to use the .net Framework 3.5... the simplest program simply will not compile.

I tried a lot of things and I am stuck and don't seem to be able to find the solution (and I really need to use a custom script that will use a reference that works with .net 3.5 ...).

To begin I changed the script component component proprieties to the framework 3.5

[image]

However, it just don't compile and complains that some references will not work with lower version of the .NETFramework

[image]

Comment: What type of task are you trying to run in a different version? If it's a Script Task, you can change it inside the task - but it's not recommended.

Comment: @FrankGoortani yes, it is a script task (i want to connect to amazonn aws), I i changed the .net version inside the task (I it required the amazon aws sdk only have .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.5 version.

Comment: The structure of the script component is different for each .NET environment. You need to manually change it to fix the errors. One other thing to consider is to create this package in SSIS 2008 and change the version to the upper one and then copy the code to 2012.